# How to pass a list of data between views in Zend?

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework

I have two dropdown list which is question and answer.
At first the answer dropdown list is empty, after the user choose a question, then it will pass the question_id to controller to run a function to get the answer. After the controller get the result, it will pass to the correspond view. Now how can I pass the result to the index view?

the index view:

```
$("#id_question").change(function() {
var data = $("#id_question").val();
var dataToSend = {question: data}
var href= '<?php echo $this->baseUrl('admin/comment/checkanswer'); ?>';

    $.ajax({ type: "POST",
        url: href,
        data: dataToSend,
        success: function(response){

                //do what u wana do
        }
        });
  });`
```

the controller:

```
public function checkanswerAction()
{
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();

    $question_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('question');

    $answer_model = new Admin_Model_DbTable_Answer();
$answer = $answer_model->getAnswersByQuestionId($question_id);

$this->view->answer = $answer;
  }
```

the checkanswer.phtml:

```
foreach ($this->answer as $key => $value)
     {
         echo '<option value="'.trim($value['id_answer']).'">'. trim($value['answer_text']) .'</option>';
       }
```

Comment: what exactly you want to do? what ever you have done here is right. Are getting any error?

Comment: currently the result will show in checkanswer.phtml...but i want it show in index.phtml...

Comment: the correct code should be like this,
 the checkanswer.phtml
`<option value="0" style="border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc !important;"><?php echo $this->translate('select_answer', $controller_name);?></option>
     <?php

         foreach ($this->answer as $key => $value)
         {
             echo '<option value="'.trim($value['id_answer']).'">'. trim($value['answer_text']) .'</option>';
         }
     ?>`

Comment: Your problem is solved right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content that should be displayed in `checkanswer.phtml` will be affected to your javascript var `response`. So if you want to display this in your page, you have to make something like this :

```
success: function(response){
    //do what u wana do
    $('#yourSelectID').html(response);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug in your action: `$this->getRequest()->getParam('question');`. It gets a parameter passed using GET but you are passing using POST. So you should use `$this->getRequest()->getPost('question');`. If you add HTML like others suggested it should work. If it doesn't, use firebug or chrome developer tools to see what was returned by server and whether wrong output is returned by the server or there's a bug in parsing it with JS.

But this approach won't work out all the time (outputting formatted HTML) because it's simply inflexible. For instance, you want to use this ajax endpoint in other application (or different platform even, such as Android), or you want to modify the data in client side before printing, etc.

The solution here is to use [context switching](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.contextswitch). Won't go into a lot of details now because I believe the link contains enough information, let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

with ajax you should always use these two things

```
   $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true); // this you have not used.
```

And in ajax resonse

```
success: function(response){

    $('#id_answer').html(response);
}
```

Comment: You don't have to disable view and layout always. Context switching does the job (and JSON context switching is damn awesome thing!) :)

Comment: @Gediminas thank you for improving my knowledge. So it means `$this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();` would work fine. Can you please tell me when both of these are required?

Comment: Well you don't want to use (disableLayout()) if the markup in the output is completely different from the majority but it's not worth creating a separate layout because it's the only case you need it. Doesn't happen too often, because most of the time pages share common <head> stuff and etc. Disabling the view (setNoRender()) in this case would break it because nothing would be outputted. In general, can't think of a case in production env. Probably never. Because if you start echoing in action, bad things will happen.